# How do I construct a DFA over the alphabet {0,1,2} that only accepts strings that have an even number of 0, 1, 2?

Tags: automata

Example: 00,0011,0022102120, etc. is fine 00112,0221100, etc. is wrong

I have done similar thing with the alphabet {0,1} and strings that have equal number of 0 and 1.

Here I run into a problem where it seems that my automata just keeps "expanding"...

Comment: @mll3 Hi! please add context and show attempt.

Comment: Can you solve the analogous binary problem?

Comment: @lulu
Yes, I get 4 states and it's quit simple but here I can't do it.

Comment: So, edit your post to include the solution for the analogous binary problem.  Not clear to me where you run into problems passing from two letters to three.

Comment: Hint: create eight states --- to +++ where ++- means you have an even number of zeroes, an even number of ones and an odd number of twos.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kctwi.png). I feel so stupid for spending a day to do this. Thanks for help

Comment: Edit your post to include your work. Providing a link, only, is grounds for deletion.